# Retriving values from one thread to other

Tags: java, multithreading

I am new to threads and I have a class which executes a thread. That thread class has a variable "errors" which will be set during its end. After that i need to access that variable in the main thread. How can it be possible. Please help me on this. Below is my snippet.

```
public class ThreadSample {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new ThreadSample().threadExample();
                // Need to access errors variable here
    }

    public void threadExample() {
        MyThread m1 = new MyThread();
    }
}

class MyThread extends Thread {
    String errors ;
    MyThread() {              
        start();
    }
    public void run() {
        // my code goes here
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: If you make the `errors` variable `volatile` you should be able to just access it as `m1.errors` after you `join()` with the thread.

Comment: Thanks a lot Gray. Please post this in answers section, so that i can accept it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:**

If you are joining with the thread (i.e. waiting for it to finish) then you can just access errors afterwards and the main thread's memory will be synchronized by the [Java thread API](http://g.oswego.edu/dl/cpj/jmm.html):

```
public String threadExample() {
    MyThread m1 = new MyThread();
    // I would not start in the thread constructor
    m1.start();
    m1.join();
    return m1.errors;
}
```

If you want to access the errors variable while the thread is still running, you have a couple of options.  You can mark the variable `volatile` which means that changes are seen by all threads:

```
volatile String errors;
```

Other ways to pass objects around is to use `AtomicReference` to set and get the object in question or to use the `synchronized` keyword to make sure that the background thread's value of errors gets synchronized with the main thread.  @claesv's answer has a good example there.

Comment: AFAIK `join` introduces a memory fence, so I'm not sure that `volatile` is required here.

Comment: Hrm.  Interesting point.  I can't find any word on this in the Java thread API.  Can you @Tudor?

Comment: I can't find it in the javadoc either, but this post by Doug Lea: http://g.oswego.edu/dl/jmm/cookbook.html mentions this in the Miscellany section at the end. Quote: `Conversely, Thread.join() requires barriers ensuring that the caller sees all stores by the terminating thread. These are normally generated by the synchronization entailed in implementations of these constructs.`

Comment: Also you can see that the `Thread.join` methods are synchronized by looking at the source code: http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/Thread.java.html

Comment: Yeah I found the same reference.  I see the `join` synchronization but I can't find the code that synchronizes on thread exit.  I'll edit my question @Tudor.  Thanks.

Comment: If the thread is roll backed is it possible to take the "errors" value still?

Comment: Sorry, what does "roll backed" mean?  If the thread has not finished you can see my recommendations in the answer.  If it finishes and `join()` returns then the errors will be available.

Comment: @gray, when i use transaction in my thread, and any exceptions happened and the transaction is getting rolled back, is it still possible to retrieve the value "errors".

Comment: If the thread exits from an exception then yes.  Again, if you join with the thread you should be able to see the errors value set by the thread.  Make sure you set errors in the catch clause.

Comment: Thanks gray, its working fine. Thanks for all of your responses.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you know how to read properties (directly or indirectly) from other classes, so I will target the multithreading issues here.

First, when accessing fields from different threads, you generally want to synchronize that access to make sure all threads see the same state:

```
public void run() {
    longOperation();
    synchronized (this) {
        errors = "some message"; 
    }
}
```

And then also add a method to MyThread for reading the error field:

```
public String getErrors() {
    synchronized (this) {
        return errors;
    }
}
```

Then, in your main class, you'd just:

```
MyThread m1 = new MyThread();
doSomeStuffWhileWaitingForLongOperation();
m1.join(); // wait for operation to finish before reading errors
String errors = m1.getErrors();
doSomethingWith(errors);
```

Comment: I don't think you need all the `synchronized` blocks. Nobody is accessing the `errors` variable except the worker thread. The main thread will get the value only after the worker has finished. Plus, reference assignments are atomic.

Comment: @Tudor, you're right. I didn't know that join introduces a memory fence, hence my comment about synchronizing access to fields.